# Python, obfuscating letters in a list

Tags: python

I have created a list `characters = list(original.lower())` to list an input of a four letter word.  This breaks down the input into sepearte characters and makes them all lowercase.

In a following function I need to call each letter that was seperated and replace them with 1 of 5 set ascii chars which are ! % *  # @

I have created the list into a var called - `obfuscate = ["!", "%", "*", "#", "@"]` and now need to but have no idea how to bring in each char and apply a random symbol to each of the letters of the input.

```
original = input("Enter a 4-letter word:  ")

    letters = isolate_letters(original) 
    obsfucate_letters(letters) 
    obfuscated = recompose_obfuscated_letters(letters)

    print("Original:  ", original)
    print("Obfuscated:  ", obfuscated)

def isolate_letters(original):

    characters = list(original.lower())
    print (characters)
    return characters


def obsfucate_letters(original):

    import random
    obfuscate = ["!", "%", "*", "#", "@"]
    print (random.choice(obfuscate))
```

EDIT:

```
def obfuscate_letters(word):

    import random
    new_word = ''
    for char in word:
        if random.random() < 0.9:
            new_word += random.choice(['!', '%', '&', '#', '@'])
        else:
            new_word += char
    letters = new_word
    print (letters)

def recompose_obfuscated_letters(letters):

        obfuscated = ''.join(letters)
        return obfuscated
```

These are my last two functions, i cannot get the letters variable returned:

this is the respons to dddd:

```
!@%!
Original: dddd 
Obfuscated: dddd
```

The top line of garble is what i need to go next to the Obfuscated bit ;/

Comment: Please provide an example of how your code should work.

Comment: Do you need to re-generate the original letters (or text) ?

Comment: If original is `'aaba'` the obfuscated word has to be, e.g., `'@@#@'`, with the same funny character repeated in place of the same repeated  character in the original word?

Comment: The obfuscation method used is to convert the input to lower case, isolate each of the 4 letters, and to replace each letter randomly using one of the following symbols:   ! % & * # @. Each of the 6 symbols has a 15% chance of being chosen, the remaining 10% means the letter will not be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to recreate the word latter. Here's a one line solution.

```
import random
def obfuscate(word):
    return ''.join([random.choice(["!", "%", "*", "#", "@"]) for char in word])
```

Explantion:

[... for ... in ...] is a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), it generates a list of random characters using the random.choice(), then the [''.join()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm), concatenate all the generated characters in a single string.

---

EDIT:

**what if the 'word' was a user input (a four letter word)?**

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter a 4-letter word:  ")
if len(user_input) == 4:
    print obfuscate(user_input)
```

**is there a way that there is a 10% chance of a letter in the word being left alone and not being changed?**

For this the list comprehension won't work (as far as I know), but you can still do it in a for loop.

```
def obsfucate(word):
    new_word = ''
    for char in word:
        if random.random() > 0.1:
            new_word += random.choice(["!", "%", "*", "#", "@"])
        else:
            new_word += char
    return new_word
```

output:

```
Enter a 4-letter word:  Damn
D%*#
```

---

EDIT2:

Actually you can use list comprehensions!

```
def obsfucate(word):
    return ''.join([random.choice(["!", "%", "*", "#", "@"]) if random.random() > 0.1 else char for char in word])
```

But for me it gets a little messy.

---

EDIT 3:

Full code should be something like:

```
import random

def obfuscate(word):
    new_word = ''
    for char in word:
        if random.random() > 0.1:
            new_word += random.choice(["!", "%", "*", "#", "@"])
        else:
            new_word += char
    return new_word

user_input = raw_input("Enter a 4-letter word:  ")
if len(user_input) == 4:
    print "Original:", user_input
    print "Obfuscate:", obfuscate(user_input)
```

Output:

```
Enter a 4-letter word:  Damn
Original: Damn
Obfuscate: D@m%
```

---

If you want to use you code as it is:

```
import random

def isolate_letters(original):
    characters = list(original.lower())
    return characters

def obsfucate(word):
    return [random.choice(["!", "%", "*", "#", "@"]) if random.random() > 0.1 else char for char in word]

def recompose_obfuscated_letters(letters):
    obfuscated = ''.join(letters)
    return obfuscated

original = input("Enter a 4-letter word:  ")

letters = isolate_letters(original)
obsfucate_letters = obsfucate(letters)
obfuscated = recompose_obfuscated_letters(obsfucate_letters)

print("Original:", original)
print("Obfuscated:", obfuscated)
```

Output:

```
Enter a 4-letter word:  Damn
Original: Damn
Obfuscated: d!!%
```

Comment: This sounds good but what if the 'word' was a user input (a four letter word)? Also is there a way that there is a 10% chance of a letter in the word being left alone and not being changed ?

Comment: There no need for the recompose function. Since new_word is a string already. Also, you are not returing the letters, you are printing it. And there's no need to create the letters variable since it's the same as new_word.

Comment: And lastly, you should edit your question, instead of my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a dictionary that can map the letter to its obfuscated character

```
import random
def encode(word, symbols):
    obfuscate = list(symbols)
    random.shuffle(obfuscate)
    d = dict(zip(word, obfuscate))
    return ''.join(d[i] for i in word)

>>> obfuscate = ["!", "%", "*", "#", "@"]
>>> word = 'test'
>>> encode(word, obfuscate)
'#%*#'
```

In the encode function, the third line creates a dictionary of the following form

```
{'s': '*',
 't': '#',
 'e': '%'}
```

Since I am shuffling the list before `zip`ing it, the map will be randomly paired. See the following few test calls

```
>>> encode(word, obfuscate)
'%!#%'
>>> encode(word, obfuscate)
'@#%@'
>>> encode(word, obfuscate)
'@#*@'
>>> encode(word, obfuscate)
'%!*%'
>>> encode(word, obfuscate)
'@*%@'
```

Comment: Where's the randomness?

Comment: @ScottHunter Edited to address the random factor of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my whole code, that you can use as is in your code excerpt.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def isolate_letters(s):
    return [c for c in s]

def obfuscate_letters(loc):
    from random import shuffle
    funny = ['!', '%', '*', '#', '@']
    # shuffle the list of funny characters
    shuffle(funny)
    # create a dictionary
    d = {c:f for f,c in zip(funny,set(loc))}
    # change in place the list of characters
    for i, c in enumerate(loc):
        loc[i] = d[c]

def recompose_obfuscated_letters(looc):
    return "".join(looc)

# here it is a copy and past from your OP (except for the spellung of obfuscate...)
original = 'funk'
letters = isolate_letters(original)
obfuscate_letters(letters)
obfuscated = recompose_obfuscated_letters(letters)

print('Original:    "%s"' % original)
print('Obfuscated:  "%s"' % obfuscated)
```

the output I have is

```
Original:    "funk"
Obfuscated:  "*#%@"
```

Key is using the `shuffle` function from the `random` module.  `shuffle` changes at random the positions of the items in a list, so that when I access the terms in `funny` sequentially, I in effect access them at random...

Next issue, I find the unique characters in the input word using `set()` and then construct a mapping, from *real* characters to *funny* characters.

The last step is, of course, go through the original list and changing all its items one by one using the mapping that we have defined two lines above.

(this last part, modifying in place the original list, follows from how the OP coded her/his example)

Answer (score 0):

A new answer because the OP has, substantially, a new question

```
def obfuscate_letters(s,funny=[c for c in "!!!%%%&&&###@@@  "]):
    from random import shuffle
    shuffle(funny)
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        s[i] = funny[i] if funny[i] != ' ' else s[i]
```

(yes, the default argument is mutable and changes at each invocation)